# Running git diff-tree with --numstat and --name-status

Tags: git-diff, git

I'm writing a script to analyze changes have been made into a git repo.
At some point I need to iterate over all the commits and obtain these information about each of them:

- Commit ID
- Date
- Commit Message
- ...
- Files changed

  - File Name
  - Type of change (Added/Modified/Removed/Renamed)
  - New File Name (in case the change type is "Renamed")
  - Number of lines added
  - Number of lines removed

I get the commit messages and dates by `git log`. The issue I have is with the files.

If I don't want to collect number of lines added/removed, I'd simply use

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -M -r abcd12345
```

The output would be something like

```
A   Readme.md
M   src/something.js
D   src/somethingelse.js
R100    tests/a/file.js tests/b/file.js
```

Which I can parse and read programmatically.

To get information about lines added/removed, I could use this:

```
git diff-tree -M -r --numstat abcd12345
```

The output would be like:

```
abcd12345
82  0   Readme.md
41  98  src/something.js
0   64  src/somethingelse.js
0   0   tests/{a => b}/file.js
```

Which is not that machine readable for renamed files.

**My question is: Is there any way to combine these two commands? It seems I can't use `--numstat` with `--name-status`.**

I can run two separate command and merge the result in my script as well. In that case, is there any other switches that I can use to make the result of the second command more machine readable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your analysis (that you need two separate commands) is correct. Use `-z` to obtain machine-readable output with `--numstat` (this disables both fancy rename encoding *and* all special-character-quoting), but note that you will then have to break lines apart at ASCII NULs instead of newlines.